# Popper popovers doesn't follow a rotating popper reference correctly

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, popper.js, popperjs

I'm working on an app that uses popper with fabric.js. The popper reference is an invisible div over the markup element. When the fabric element rotates the popover doesn't properly rotate with the markup, as it only properly follow the reference for the "top right" quadrant when rotating the element in a circle(I have a linked codepen that you can try as as an example, it's hard to explain haha.). I'm wondering if it's possible to both:

A.) Have the popper popover follow the markup when rotating. (This is the preferred option for me!)
B.) If that doesn't work, Have the popover element be static so it doesn't move when rotating, but does when moving have the popover element move so the invisible markup div doesn't clip.

Any suggestions here would be suggested! I have a rough `rotationChanger` method that I thought would work, but causes an infinite loop that freezes my window.

https://codepen.io/freddie-pike/pen/YzXGwPe